# Application unfortunately has stopped working

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make an interface with the Telephone from the Hijack, so I'm trying to Record the Data (sound) sent from the Hijack. When I'm trying this code using Eclipse, it shows me that the program has unfortunately stopped, I thought that I'm using a peripheral the emulator can't access on the PC, so I moved it to My smartphone and it shows the same problem.

Here is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private MediaRecorder myAudioRecorder;
    private String outputFile = null;
    private Button start,stop,play;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        start = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        stop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        play = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);

        stop.setEnabled(false);
        play.setEnabled(false);
        outputFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getAbsolutePath() + "/myrecording.3gp";

        myAudioRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        myAudioRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        myAudioRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        myAudioRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
        myAudioRecorder.setOutputFile(outputFile);
    }

    public void start(View view){
        try {
            myAudioRecorder.prepare();
            myAudioRecorder.start();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        start.setEnabled(false);
        stop.setEnabled(true);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Recording started", 
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void stop(View view){
        myAudioRecorder.stop();
        myAudioRecorder.release();
        myAudioRecorder  = null;
        stop.setEnabled(false);
        play.setEnabled(true);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Audio recorded successfully",
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void play(View view) throws IllegalArgumentException,   
            SecurityException, IllegalStateException, IOException{
        MediaPlayer m = new MediaPlayer();
        m.setDataSource(outputFile);
        m.prepare();
        m.start();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Playing audio", 
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

here is the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.audiocapture"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

here is the main_activity.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding ="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="@string/Recording"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@android:drawable/presence_audio_online" 
        android:contentDescription="@string/imageViewDescription" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="67dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:onClick="start"
        android:text="@string/start" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:onClick="stop"
        android:text="@string/stop" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="play"
        android:text="@string/play" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: post logcat to help u

Comment: Please post the logcat error, so that we can help you

Comment: Yes, it has (to the "question" in the title). Please read: http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/index.html and the subtopics.

Comment: You are missing permission to READ and WRITE to sd card

Comment: yes, I'm trying to post Logcat but it didn't show me any message?

Comment: Okay Plz @HussainMarvi I need to Know how to use this permission if you have any Tutorial showing this.

Comment: Add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>` in your android manifest file.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.audiocapture"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />


   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>     
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission-group.HARDWARE_CONTROLS"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission-group.MICROPHONE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: I do that before you tell me, thanks again ,um trying ,I hope it work,
thank you for your great help

Comment: thanks it works with me :) :) 
I need another help, the Logcat didn't show any message.

Comment: There is a dropdown in logcat and select errors. By default it shows verbose.. and please up vote as it worked..